# How many writes per second to a MySQL server can I reasonably expect?

Tags: mysql, performance

We're running a custom ad server solution and, in some cases, we store and increment/decrement counts and aggregated values in MySQL, for optimization.

I understand keeping counts in MySQL is not ideal, although I'm not 100% sure why. My guess is that writes on disk are slower than to memory, so keeping counts in Redis would work better than keeping them in MySQL. But this would add a few extra layers of complexity to our system and would imply serious changes on multiple components.

In the past, we've saw the connection count piling up and the CPU utilization going up, but after caching most of the requests and switching to faster disks we've managed to move up this limit. We're currently handling a 10-20 million requests per day with a master-slave MySQL configuration, where the writes are sent to the master and most reads are done from the slave. Also, adding another slave server would not be a problem at all.

My concern is related to the writes on master, although they are just tiny operations of incrementing a row in each of 5 tables.

So my question is: how many such small writes per second can I expect to safely perform in MySQL before hitting a limit, based on your experience? I hear people handling 100k connections simultaneously, but what if all these connections try to increment a row in the same second? What would be a good strategy to scale this up when needed?

Thanks!

Comment: Additional information request for your MySQL instance. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For InnoDB, you will probably be OK with SSDs.

20M `UPDATEs` per day = 230/second; more if there are spikes.

Spinning disk (HDD):  100 writes per second.

SSD:  Maybe 1000/sec.

Batched `INSERTs` run faster.

Some variants of RAID run faster.

A RAID controller with Battery Backed Write Cache runs really fast (for writes) (until the cache is saturated).

For keeping "likes" or "views" or "clicks" it is *probably* better to keep the counters in a separate table from the rest of the columns about the page/product/whatever.  This way, updating the counter and dealing with the other data interfere less.

There are several settings to consider tuning:

`innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2`  (Tradeoff for speed instead of security)

`sync_binlog = OFF`

Combine multiple actions into a single `BEGIN..COMMIT` transaction.  But be cautious about deadlocks, etc.

Perhaps you did not mean 100K *connections*?  That is a huge number.  More than a few dozen running threads (irrespective of the number of sleeping threads) is quite a lot.

Another approach to counting clicks is not to record them in real time, but scrape the web server log every, say, hour.  Have a separate process to count all the clicks for the hour (or each 5 minutes or whatever) into a single number to feed to an `UPDATE`.  That would be more work for a separate server, but very little effort for the database.

Comment: Thanks for a great, detailed answer!

Comment: Sources for any of these #s?

Comment: @broofa - Not really; mostly from 2 decades of experience with MySQL.  My website has a compilation of various things like this:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/

Answer (score 1):

IF you are insisting to use MySql then I suggest you to use In Memory Tables

```
CREATE TABLE TableName (Column1 INT) ENGINE = MEMORY;
```

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

**BTW**

> So my question is: how many such small writes per second can I expect
>   to safely perform in MySQL before hitting a limit, based on your
>   experience?

I don't think that anyone here can give you clear answer.

Comment: @user1782560   From the MEMORY reference, read carefully, please.  The MEMORY storage engine (formerly known as HEAP) creates special-purpose tables with contents that are stored in memory. Because the data is vulnerable to crashes, hardware issues, or power outages, only use these tables as temporary work areas or read-only caches for data pulled from other tables.

Before you take this leap.

Comment: Occasionally I see benchmarks that show InnoDB to be faster than MEMORY.  I can see this especially for 'concurrent' access, plus batched inserts, etc.